# How do I take away from a variable a certain number of times every second javascript/html?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to subtract a certain amount from variable every second. How do I do that? When I search 'how to take away from a variable javascript', two things show up, how to delete a variable, and how to take away a certain number off a variable all at once. So I just searched up, how to say 'per second' in javascript and I would try to figure the other part on my own and I could not find that either.

Thanks in advance!

~John

Comment: What have  you tried? Google for `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 0):

You typically use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) for this, so...

```
var intervalId = setInterval(
  function() {
    // This function will be executed once every second (give or take)
    // You can subtract from your variable here

    // If you're done running, you can stop the interval using...
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, 1000, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 10;
function reduce() {
   console.log(x);
   x = x-1;
   if (x === 0) return; 
   setTimeout(reduce, 1000); 
}
reduce();
```